# Information from QTableWidget Cell to QTextBrowser - PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am trying to create a very simple application where once a button is click the information from the cell is displayed in the text browser but I can't get it to work. I have tried a couple of the methods such as copy and setHtml but it won't copy over.

I am using PySide, Python 2.7 and I have created these signals within the Qt Designer

```
def get_cell_content(self):
    currentRow = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    if currentRow > -1:
        text = (self.tableWidget.item(currentRow, 0).text(), )

    self.textBrowser.setHtml(text)
```

The button to make it work

```
    self.getText.clicked.connect(self.get_cell_content)
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work? Currently it displays the rows index in the textBrowser but I would like it to show the current cell.

Comment: A way: define a SLOT `handleCellDoubleClicked(int, int)`, retrieve the content from this particular cell. Set the text browser content.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show the text of the current cell you should also retrieve the index of the column :

```
def get_cell_content(self):
    currentRow = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    currentCol = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
    if currentRow > -1:
        text = (self.tableWidget.item(currentRow, currentCol).text(), )

    self.textBrowser.setHtml(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that may help:

```
text = self.tableWidget.item(currentRow, 0).text()
# remove the extra ()s
```

Are you sure you want a textBrowser rather than textEdit, and its setPlainText() method? The text browser provides navigation through links, but handles a lot of updating the display automatically.